# Xcode 9 code snippets bug

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, code-snippets

I have a list of code snippets that works perfectly in **Xcode 8.3.3**, but in **Xcode 9** I don't see them when I start typing. I tried to change **Completion Scopes** and I've got a new bug: when I press tab my snippet completes incorrectly as seen in the screenshot below. [image]

Here is the repository with [source of snippets](https://github.com/ismetanin/XcodeCodeSnippets).

Let me know how to fix this bug please.

Answer (score 2):

I also had many comment-scope snippets starting with `//`, and I support your question.

I don't know how to make them work, but I can propose a temporary solution. Set **Completion Scopes** to **All** and remove `//` from the prefix. Then add `//` to the snippet body:

```
    MARK: - Private helpers => // MARK: - Private helpers
```

Comment: Thank you, It's interesting solution